# Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon 3rd Gen - No W-Fi Adapter Found

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, lenovo, thinkpad

I have been using my Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon 3rd Gen with no problem for close to a year now with no problem, until now. Booting up this afternoon, it cannot connect to a network via Wi-Fi.

Looking through askubuntu, I've searched through previous solutions with no success. Please help.

Here are the outputs of some of the commands I've seen in other threads. Let me know if more information is needed to figure this one out!

**rfkill list all**

```
1: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**uname -r**

```
4.15.0-46-generic
```

**lsb_release -a**

```
No LSB modules are available.
```

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

**sudo lshw -C network**

```
*-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 19
   bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
   logical name: enp0s25
   version: 03
   serial: 54:ee:75:5a:23:e8
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.2-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:44 memory:f1100000-f111ffff memory:f113d000-f113dfff ioport:3060(size=32)

*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: bnep0
   serial: 5c:e0:c5:51:b4:3a
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes ip=192.168.44.192 multicast=yes
```

Edit: Additional information.

Strangely enough, rebooting the computer fixes the issue temporarily, however when it goes to and returns from sleep mode, it can no longer find the Wi-Fi adapter.

Following is the output of Marmayogi's suggested commands:

**sudo lshw -short -class network**

```
H/W path        Device     Class          Description
=====================================================
/0/100/19       enp0s25    network        Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM
/0/100/1c.1/0   wlp4s0     network        Illegal Vendor ID
```

**nmcli device**

```
DEVICE             TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION 
38:78:62:9D:79:A9  bt        disconnected  --         
enp0s25            ethernet  unavailable   --         
wlp4s0             wifi      unavailable   --         
lo                 loopback  unmanaged     --
```

**ip addr show**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 54:ee:75:5a:23:e8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5c:e0:c5:51:b4:36 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**rfkill**

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE                   SOFT      HARD
 1 bluetooth tpacpi_bluetooth_sw unblocked unblocked
 2 wlan      phy0                unblocked unblocked
 4 bluetooth hci0                unblocked unblocked
```

**ls -l /etc/resolv.conf**

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 sep  3  2018 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the output of the following commands: 1. `sudo lshw -short -class network` 2. `nmcli device` 3. `ip addr show`  4. `rfkill` and 5. `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @Marmayogi done!

Comment: Please @Emil Gunnberg Querat, you post output of this command: `nmcli device show wlp4s0 | grep IP4.DNS`

Comment: Error: Device 'wlp4s0' not found.

Comment: Your wi-fi interface adapter is totally down and unavailable from ubuntu. Can you connect to Wi-Fi from windows-10? Is it working? Please post the output of the command `dmesg | grep -i wlp4s0`.

Comment: No output what so ever... The adapter was down last weekend, but was working all week through to friday, when it shut down again. Seems odd. A year back I had the computer running windows 10, until I ran into this problem as well. Installed Ubuntu 18.04, and the Wi-Fi adapter was running fine again, until now.

Comment: Please issue command `sudo ip link set dev wlp4s0 up` to enable WiFi. Try to connect to internet. Also, post the output of commands `nmcli device | grep wlp4s0` and `rfkill | grep wlan`